# .Net Membership Provider and First and Last Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using the default **.NET Membership Provider** for user management in my site.

On creating a user I would like to set a first name and last name, as provided by the user.  Any idea how I might do this?

Comment: You could create a custom membership provider. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838371/asp-net-mvc-custom-membership-provider-how-to-overload-createuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the built-in profile functionality in ASP.NET. Here's a good explanation of how it works within MVC specifically:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1327/profile-provider-in-aspnet-mvc/

And here is the the MSDN article about profiles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Comment: Profile is fine if you just need to get at some information on occasion, one field at a time.  However, it quickly becomes unamanagale as the amount of info grows.

Comment: @MystereMan what would you suggest instead of profile provider?

Comment: @mask8 - you usually create your own user table, then add the ProviderUserKey to it so you can lookup data based on the user id.