# How use custom object through website exactly like membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, membership, membership-provider

could you explain to me how can I store and use a custom object exactly like we use the asp.net MVC membership through a website ? I use very often the same one table from my database and I want to stop asking my server to retreive this same information on every page. I can't use cookie because I have some important information into this and I don't use session because I want this object accessible like the membership. After user login, I would like to set this information once and for all into this object until it disconnects.

Examples...

1. The very normal membership :

   MembershipUser UserAccount = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
2. My custom data object I want to use

   MyCustomData customData = Membership.GetCustomData(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to override something like here: [ASP.NET MVC Custom Membership Provider - How to overload CreateUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838371/asp-net-mvc-custom-membership-provider-how-to-overload-createuser) or create your custom membership provider and add extra methods: [Custom Membership Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) (I prefer this)